# List in xsl schema mapping Java classes

Tags: xml, spring, list, xsd, xml-schema-collection

How the list can be implemented in the XML schema (xsd )? So that the mapping with the Java class should create variable of java.util.List Type instead of Object Type ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `maxOccurs="unbounded"` in elements or list type in attributes. Something like:

```
<xs:element name="strings" type="xs:string" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>

<xs:attribute name="ints" type="ints"/>

<xs:simpleType name="ints">
  <xs:list itemType="xs:int"/>
</xs:simpleType>
```

However, specific mapping depends on the library you use.